# SlackApi - Missing Linebreaks

Tags: c#, .net, slack-api

I'm sending data to a slack channel with webhook integration.
But when i include a linebreak (\n) i get at http 500. When I url encode the linebreak i see the encoded value, not a real line break in slacn

```
            string body = "foo"
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(feedEntry.Link ))
            {
                body +=  " \n <" + feedEntry.Link +">";
            }           
            body = "{\"text\": \"" + body+ "\"}";

            using(var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var msg = new StringContent(body);
                var result = await client.PostAsync(url, msg);
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\\n` instead of `\n`.  The string will then contain `\` followed by `n` which is valid JSON and will turn into a newline char by the JSON parser.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't realize that i need a string / json newline